# Stuck creating a django posts filter

Tags: python, django

I need to filter the posts by the options selected between: "most commented" "category" "date". This is actually my code:

models:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):

class BlogPostObjects(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(status='publicado')

options = (
    ('borrador', 'Borrador'),
    ('publicado', 'Publicado')
)
categoria = models.ForeignKey(BlogCategoria, on_delete=models.PROTECT,default=1)
titulo = models.CharField(max_length=250)
excerpt = models.TextField(null=True)
contenido = models.TextField()
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publicado',null=False, unique=True)
publicado = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
autor = models.ForeignKey(Usuario,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="autor")
status = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=options,default='borrador')
imagen = models.ImageField(default= "empty.jpg" ,null=True, blank = True)
objects = models.Manager()
postobjects = BlogPostObjects()

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-publicado',)
    db_table= "blog_post"
```

At the moment I tried creating a custom filter like:

```
class PostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
class Meta:
    model: BlogPost
    fields: ['categoria','publicado']
```

with this views:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ListarAdmin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["filter"] = PostFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
    return context
```

And this template

```
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" style="padding:50px;" method="GET">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 " name="name_categoria" type="search" placeholder="Ingrese nombre del producto..." aria-label="Search" value="{{filter}}">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Buscar</button>
              </div>
          </div>
    </form>
```

expecting to see only the posts which have the category name written, but it doesn't work

Comment: What have you tried yet? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @jmangold eddited the post to explain it better

Answer (score 0):

The filter object you provide in the context is an object and the templating language cannot interpret this.

Generally you need to iterate through the queryset in your template:

```
{% for obj in filter.qs %}
    # do something with obj
{% endfor %}
```

For your needs I would recommend you a dropdown menu instead of an search input field:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
  <select class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="name_categoria" id="categoria" placeholder="Ingrese nombre del producto...">
    {% for obj in filter.qs %}
        # Every obj is an instance of BlogCategoria
        <option value="obj.name">obj.name</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
```

Be sure, that you name the attributes of the `<select-input>` and `<option>` correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help!